# Why do we need doFirst block in the gradle tasks?

Tags: build.gradle, gradle-task

From my testing, both

```
task taskA {
    doFirst {
        println("$name first")
    }
    doLast {
        println("$name second")
    }
}
```

and

```
task taskB {
    doLast {
        println("$name first")
        println("$name second")
    }
}
```

executes in the same order.

What is the significance of having a separate `doFirst` block? Can something else happen between the execution of `doFirst` and `doLast`?

I have gone through the gradle docs section on [tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html). The examples also seem to use just `doLast`